# Can using .map() twice over the same array be avoided even though the components the map() renders are not siblings?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

So, I have some working code, but I just feel like there is a solution where I can use just one .map() and I'm not seeing it.

The components are not siblings (they don't share the same parent component), so to solve this I just did .map() twice over the same array of objects, but I feel like that is a waste of resources and that there must be a better solution for this kind of situation.

Here's the code

```
<div className="pricepoints-form">
    <Tabs className="tabs">
        <TabList>
            {
                this.state.pricepointsData.map(pricepoint => (
                    <Tab className="tab">{pricepoint.name}</Tab>
                ))
            }
        </TabList>
        {
            this.state.pricepointsData.map(pricepoint => (
                <TabPanel>
                    <Pricepoint
                        pricepoint={pricepoint}
                        displayLast4={this.state.displayLast4}
                    />
                </TabPanel>
            ))
        }
    </Tabs>
</div>
```

Comment: Premature optimization is the root of all evil. I think this code looks nice and anything you did to make it happen in one `map` would make it a lot uglier and gain you very little.

Comment: I don't see any other method for achieving the required layout without looping through the data twice, using `map` or otherwise. I also highly doubt the use of `map` twice will in any way noticeably impact the performance of your app.

Comment: Thanks @Nathan and fubar , I'll leave it like this then. I'll leave the question open for another hour to see if anyone has any ideas that wouldn't be awful, if not, I'll close this.

Comment: You could do something like this: `components = this.state.pricepointsData.map(pricepoint => [(
        <Tab className="tab">{pricepoint.name}</Tab>
    ),(
        <TabPanel>
            <Pricepoint
                pricepoint={pricepoint}
                displayLast4={this.state.displayLast4}
            />
        </TabPanel>
    )])`. Then you'd end up mapping over that to create your UI anyway though so still 2 maps.

Comment: Well you could have a function that loops through the list once, building 2 separate arrays as it goes, then just render those 2 arrays in their respective parent. That way you'd only loop through the data array once. But as others said, I really wouldn't bother, it's not as neat and most likely won't help much if at all. And even if you want to optimise things down the line then there'll be plenty of other things more important than this.

Comment: Yeah, all in all, even if I make an array of components, I'll still have to map twice to render that array out, since the number of tabs varies depending on the data that's provided. Looks like there isn't a more elegant solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can using `.map()` twice over the same array be avoided even though the components the map() renders are not siblings?

Technically, yes it's possible. But lets look at what you're really optimizing away here.

`map` is essentially a `for` loop that assigns values to a new array:

```
// example
function map(transform) {
  const ret = []
  for (let i = 0; i < this.length; i++) {
    ret.push(transform(this[i], i, this))
  }
  return ret
}
```

what this means is you could replace the map function with your own function that runs a loop and creates *two* arrays:

```
function myMap(transform1, transform2) {
  const r1 = []
  const r2 = []
  for (let i = 0; i < this.length; i++) {
    r1.push(transform1(this[i], i, this))
    r2.push(transform2(this[i], i, this))
  }
  return [r1, r2]
}
```

Using this new function would be awkward at best:

```
const [tabs, panels] = myMap.call(this.state.pricepointsData, pricepoint => (...), pricepoint => (...))

...
<TabList>
  { tabs }
</TabList>
{ panels }
...
```

So the real question should be: Is this abstraction worth it?

And to that I have a counter-question:

What's larger, 2x1 or 1x2?

You could use two loops that each do one thing (2 `map` calls), or you could use a single loop that does two things (1 `myMap` call).

Comment: Thanks for the anwser!